# How to do Teamcity remote run in script?

Tags: teamcity

My question is How to do Teamcity remote run in script(shell or dos)?

I can do normal teamcity remote run, but this means the checkout and replace new files things is controled by teamcity itself, sometimes I want do checkout data in my script.

Because often we will meet a NT agent have some problem and the checkout will fail, if we can do a pre-clean before the checkout, it will not be a problem.

I will appreciate if anyone can give advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try command-line remote run tool for TeamCity:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Command+Line+Remote+Run+Tool

Comment: The instructions for use are terrible